# Pandas how to resample index when there are duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table as shown:

```
DateAdded,SerialNo,Price,SellerID
2019-12-08,B0043T7FXE,23.99,A3ACUPJ4C2HX16
2019-12-08,B00WBJGUA2,159.0,AKFIC6WL0CEQJ
2019-12-08,B0131RG6VK,224.0,AWJMXP5IJRVY4
2019-12-08,B0177FO9X4,379.99,A3BZ4PFG2UQP4O
2019-12-08,B01D1TTHGO,174.99,A6IE4BQ0ZDGZL
2019-12-08,B01H0REL0U,375.0,A3CYTIH19FT9YG
2019-12-08,B01I3I9L8M,177.98,A1JN7BJ51N99LT
2019-12-08,B01M65EKLG,224.73,ANRQ8YPYMWERJ
2019-12-08,B01M66NWOQ,286.48,AUV5OXA4KGE56
2019-12-08,B01MAW2294,229.99,A3SVXW1QA62AY5
```

I want to resample the dataframe into 15 minute intervals (the DateAdded column is already in timestamp format but for some reason it doesn't show it??) and forward fill every other column.

I tried:

```
df1 = df1.resample('15min',on='DateAdded').ffill()
```

and got the error:

ValueError: Upsampling from level= or on= selection is not supported, use .set_index(...) to explicitly set index to datetime-like

I also tried setting index but it won't work either because there are duplicates in the date and this error pops up:

ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit

Anyone able to help?
Thanks

Comment: I think you should find out why your time is not carried over to your `DateAdded` column first.

Comment: _the DateAdded column is already in timestamp format_: doesn't look like it. It's more like date format